# Mac OSx terminal : "not a valid identifier" on function definition

Tags: shell, sh, zsh

I have a bash script in which I define the below function,

```
function start-if-exists()
{
    if [ "`docker container ls -a|grep $1`" ]; then
        echo "Container $1 exists. Starting $1..."
        return `docker start $1`
    else
        echo "Container $1 doesn't exists."
        return ""
    fi
}
```

While executing the above function in terminal(`zsh`) directly I am not getting any error. But when I execute it using `sh` command(`sh my_script.sh`), I am getting the below error.

> my_script.sh: line 10: `start-if-exists': not a valid identifier

where `my_script.sh` is the name of file.

What am I missing that my script works with `zsh` but fails in `sh`?

Comment: Which shell is exactly your `sh`? You can find out by looking at the target of the symbolic link: `realpath /bin/sh`.

Comment: @user803422: The question asks about Mac OS X. On Mac OS X or macOS, `realpath` is not present, and `/bin/sh` is not a symbolic link, unless non-Apple modifications have been made to the system.

Comment: `return` is only used to return an 8-bit status code, not arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/bin/sh` is `bash`, but, when started as `/bin/sh`, it starts in POSIX mode. According to the `bash` man page, in POSIX mode:

> 16. Function names must be valid shell `name's.  That is, they may not
>        contain characters other than letters, digits, and underscores, and
>        may not start with a digit.  Declaring a function with an invalid
>        name causes a fatal syntax error in non-interactive shells.

A note about how to figure things like this out:

- At the Terminal command line, I executed `/bin/sh --version` to see information about it. It printed “GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)”.
- Then I referred to the `bash` man page, using the command `man bash`. Since that is long, you might prefer to save a copy to a file and view it in your preferred text editor. The raw `man` output includes archaic underscores and backspaces. You can get a copy without these by executing `man bash | col -b > file.txt`.
- In the man page, I searched for ”sh” (as a complete word, not a raw search for those letters, since they appear as parts of many unrelated words). This quickly revealed discussion that bash behaves differently when started as “sh”; it starts in POSIX mode.
- Searching further for “POSIX” revealed a list of things that are different in POSIX mode.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is not always bash. It can be `dash`, `ash`, etc.

Comment: @user803422: The question asks about Mac OS X, not Unix in general. On Mac OS X, `sh` is GNU bash unless non-Apple modifications have been made to the system.

Comment: The problem was fixed when I change the '-' with '_'.